How can I use Carbon::setTestNow() to influence the results of the FakerPHP dateTimeBetween method?
I'm using model factory methods in my Laravel test suite that return date ranges. For instance:
class WorkSiteFactory extends Factory
{
  // ... Other factory stuff....

  /**
  * Indicate that the Permit status is fully approved.
  */
  public function withApprovedPermit(): self
  {
      return $this->state([
        'permit_paid_at' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-12 days', '-8 days'),
        'permit_approved_at' => $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-12 days', '-8 days')
      ]);
  }
}

In tests, I'll sometimes mock the date using Carbon::setTestNow() and then make my test assertions. But unfortunately the dateTimeBetween usages don't respond to the mocked date.
use App\Models\WorkSite;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Tests\TestCase;

class SchedulerControllerTest extends TestCase
{

    /** @test */
    public function index_returns_correct_number_of_work_sites(): void
    {  
        // Set the mocked "now" time
        $mockNow = Carbon::parse('2024-10-01');
        Carbon::setTestNow($mockNow);
    

        // Incomplete WorkSites won't show up as available
        WorkSite::factory()
            ->count(2)
            ->incomplete()
            ->create();
         
        // 4 WorkSites Ready to Work
        $workSites = WorkSite::factory()
            ->count(4)
            ->readyToWork() 
            ->withApprovedPermit() // ❌ <- this should set the permit dates correctly but it doesn't adjust according to the mocked date
            ->create();

        $response = $this
            ->actingAs(User::factory()->create())
            ->get(route('scheduler.index'))
            ->assertOk();

        // Then asserting that the right number of
        // WorkSites are returned according to the date...
        // ...
    }
}

I've done some source diving and thought maybe there was a way to override "now" in the Faker package but I don't see any.
I've also tried to wrap the returned values in Carbon::instance() and Carbon::parse(), both didn't work.
I'm sure there's a hacky way of writing a method that takes the result of the Faker and adjusts it according to the Carbon::now() time but that seems like the wrong solution.
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: Since faker doesn't rely at all on Carbon and mocked dates, I created my own little helper function that relies on Laravel's now() function so you can mock it as needed. In case anyone is interested, here's what I came up with:

public function randomCarbonDateBetween(int|string $min, int|string $max): Carbon
{
    [$min, $max] = [(int) $min, (int) $max]; // force casting as ints

    if ($min > $max) {
        throw new Exception('Minimum date must be less than maximum date.');
    }

    return now()->addDays(random_int($min, $max));
}

// Can be used with strings or ints

// between 25 days ago and 25 days from now
$randomDayUsingInt = randomCarbonDateBetween(-25, 25);
$randomDayUsingStrings = randomCarbonDateBetween('-25', '+25');

// You can even use it as a replacement from Faker's dateTimeBetween
$randomDayUsingFakerFormat = randomCarbonDateBetween('-25 days', '+25 days');

// The passed Unit is NOT respected
// The following have equal results
randomCarbonDateBetween('-25 days', '+25 days'); // -25 to 25 days
randomCarbonDateBetween('-25 years', '+25 months'); // -25 to 25 days


Based on Carbon's documentation, you can use some ways:

Carbon::parse('-12 days')->daysUntil('-8 days');
Carbon::parse('-12 days')->diff('-8 days')->stepBy('day');
CarbonPeriod::between('-12 days', '-8 days');

This will give you an iterable from initial date to end date, what you can do is then use faker to get a random day from that iterable.
If you do this, you will always use Carbon, so you can use Carbon::setTestNow(now()) anywhere and then the factory will take that into account:
// Code before you trigger factory
$mockNow = Carbon::parse('2024-10-01');
Carbon::setTestNow($mockNow);

// Part of the factory

// Instead of
$this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-12 days', '-8 days');

// Use
$this->faker->randomElement(\Carbon\CarbonPeriod::between('-12 days', '-8 days'));

I saw you are using Carbon::setTestNow(), prefer to use "native" Laravel way of doing it:
// Instead of
$mockNow = Carbon::parse('2024-10-01');
Carbon::setTestNow($mockNow);

// Use
$this->travelTo(Carbon::parse('2024-10-01'));


Thanks for this idea but it's a little more verbose than I would like (in terms of using it across many tests). And, yes, I generally use Laravel's travelTo() but asked the question using setTestNow() to make it easier for anyone not coming from Laravel. Check out the helper function I added to the original question if you're interested.

Faker is using PHP's DateTime class and doesn't use Carbon (which extends DateTime) in any way.
As the model factory is only used in the test suites, you can add a parameter to withApprovedPermit() where you can provide a DateTime object.
Or you can set the Date of the objects manually after creation (provided you have the required setters)
  public function withApprovedPermit(?DateTime $permitDate = null): self
  {
      return $this->state([
        'permit_paid_at' => $permitDate ?? $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-12 days', '-8 days'),
        'permit_approved_at' => $permitDate ?? $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-12 days', '-8 days')
      ]);
  }

Here is the updated method, if you provide an argument it will take it and set it as the date, otherwise it would use the DateTime from Faker.

thanks @ikyuchokov. I was thinking about injecting the date as a param into the date-related methods but it didn't seem very clean. Could you add a code block to your answer with an example of how I would use the DateTime $date param if I passed it into that method? I'm not sure how I'd override the default faker behavior.

You can check my updated answer.

Thanks for your help but I don't think this quite answers my question. I've come up with my own helper method to select a random day. Gonna post it in the original question. LMK what you think
